# How do I make a NSTextField grayed out?

Tags: cocoa, nstextfield

I have multiple text fields, and I was wondering how to make them grayed out
I tried
`[textfield setEditable:NO]` and `[textfield setEnabled:NO]`
What am I missing?

I connected the text field to a `IBOutlet NSTextField *textfield;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried here using a button to switch the behavior:

```
- (IBAction)switchEnabled:(id)sender {
    [_textfield setEnabled: ![_textfield isEnabled]];
}

- (IBAction)switchEditable:(id)sender {
    [_textfield setEditable: ![_textfield isEditable]];
}
```

Works like a charm! The first grays the text field out, the second denies user input only. Sure you connected the outlets right?

Comment: I just use self.[name]

Comment: I figured it out. I was doing it in a weird button.